# Intercalar listas en python

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con este código y quiero que me salgan los resultados de la siguiente manera, pero no encuentro el error.

[a]&[1, 2] = {[a, 1, 2], [1, a, 2], [1, 2, a]}

[a, b]&[1, 2] = {[a, b, 1, 2], [, a, 1, b, 2], [a, 1, 2, b], [1, a, b, 2], [1, a, 2, b], [1, 2, a, b]}

[a, b, c]&[1, 2] = {[a, b, c, 1, 2], [a, b, 1, c, 2], [a, b, 1, 2, c], [a, 1, b, c, 2], [a, 1, b, 2, c],[a, 1, 2, b, c], [1, a, b, c, 2], [1, a, b, 2, c], [1, a, 2, b, c], [1, 2, a, b, c]}

```
def leer_lista(lista):
    no_elem = int(input("Ingresa el número de elementos de la lista: "))
    
    for i in range(1, no_elem + 1):
        elem_i = input()
        lista.append(elem_i)

   
def intercalado(lista1, lista2):
    result = list()
    if (len(lista1) == 0 or len(lista2) == 0):
        lista3 = lista1 + lista2
        result.append(lista3)
        return result
    
    a0 = [lista1[0]]
    b0 = [lista2[0]]
    
    lista1.pop(0)
    lista2.pop(0)
    
    result = (concatenar_mult(a0 , intercalado(lista1,concatenar( b0, lista2)))) +\
             (concatenar_mult(b0 , intercalado(concatenar(a0 , lista1), lista2)))
    
    return result

def concatenar(lista1, lista2):
    return lista1 + lista2

def concatenar_mult(lista1, lista2):
    for i in range (0,len(lista2)):
        lista2[i] = lista1 + lista2[i]
    return lista2


#función principal
resultado = list()
a = list()
b = list()

print("CALCULADORA DE INTERCALADO ENTRE DOS LISTAS\n")

while (0 < 1):
    print("LISTA A:")
    leer_lista(a)
    print("LISTA B:")
    leer_lista(b)
    c = concatenar(a,b)

    resultado = intercalado(a, b)
    
    print(resultado)
    #print(c)
    
    print("¿Desea hacer otro cálculo?   1. Sí.   2. No.")
    opcion = int(input())
    
    if (opcion == 2):
        break
```

Comment: Un ejemplo es que el usuario meta un arreglo de tres que seria [a, b, c] y que después un arreglo de [1, 2] tiene que salir una lista de listas que contenga {[a, b, c, 1, 2], [a, b, 1, c, 2], [a, b, 1, 2, c], [a, 1, b, c, 2], [a, 1, b, 2, c],[a, 1, 2, b, c], [1, a, b, c, 2], [1, a, b, 2, c], [1, a, 2, b, c], [1, 2, a, b, c]}

Answer (score 1):

Si tuviéramos que intercalar un elemento en una lista, se podría hacer con la siguiente función:

```py
def intercala_uno(a, lst):
    return [lst[:i] + [a] + lst[i:] for i in range(len(lst)+1)]
```

Para el caso más general, lo mejor es recurrir a una función recursiva:

```py
def intercala(lst1, lst2):
    if len(lst1) == 0:
        return [lst2]
    elif len(lst2) == 0:
        return [lst1]
    else:
        (head, *tail) = lst1
        return [
            fst + [head] + ys
            for (fst, snd) in split(lst2)
            for ys in intercala(tail, snd) ]
 
def split(lst):
    return ((lst[:i], lst[i:]) for i in range(len(lst)+1))
```

Los dos primeros *ifs* son condiciones de finalización. Con `split()` rebanamos la lista en dos partes para insertar un elemento entre medio.

Para python 3.10 se puede emplear la nueva sintáxis *match*:

```py
def intercala(lst1, lst2):
    match (lst1, lst2):
        case ([],_):
            return [lst2]
        case (_, []):
            return [lst1]
        case ((head,*tail), lst2):
            return [
                fst + [head] + ys
                for (fst, snd) in split(lst2)
                for ys in intercala(tail, snd) ]
```

---

**Editado**: añado una demo:

```py
from pprint import pprint

lista1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lista2 = [1, 2]

resultado = intercala(lista1, lista2)

pprint(resultado)
```

Da como resultado:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2],
 ['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 2],
 ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 'c'],
 ['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2],
 ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c'],
 ['a', 1, 2, 'b', 'c'],
 [1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2],
 [1, 'a', 'b', 2, 'c'],
 [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'c'],
 [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']]
```

---

**Editado**: cuando hay funciones recursivas, es siempre recomendable completar la signatura de las funciones con sus tipos de datos. añado tipos y código completo:

```
from typing import Iterator

def split(lst: list) -> Iterator[tuple[list, list]]:
    return ((lst[:i], lst[i:]) for i in range(len(lst)+1))

def intercala(lst1: list, lst2: list) -> list[list]:
    match (lst1, lst2):
        case ([],_):
            return [lst2]
        case (_, []):
            return [lst1]
        case ((head,*tail), lst2):
            return [
                fst + [head] + ys
                for (fst, snd) in split(lst2)
                for ys in intercala(tail, snd) ]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar una demo del funcionamiento con los datos del OP?

Comment: Ya ni me acuerdo de qué iba esto. ¿Que es el OP?

Comment: El Original Poster. Autor de la pregunta. Todavía voy en la 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Para atacar este problema, propongo dividirlo en 2 subproblemas:

**Problema 1:** Desplazamiento de un (1) elemento en una lista.
Propuesta: Función que desplace cualquier elemento de una `lista` que esté en una `pos_inicio` a una posición final deseada `pos_final`. Como el desplazamiento es hacia la derecha, propongo que la `pos_final` sea un número `<= 0`, entonces:

```
def desplazar(lista, pos_inicio, pos_final):
    elem = lista[pos_inicio]
    lista.pop(pos_inicio) # Eliminar el elemento de la lista
    sub_res = []
    for i in range(pos_inicio+1, len(lista)+pos_final+1):
        sublista1 = lista[:i]
        sublista2 = lista[i:]
        sublista1.append(elem)#.extend(sublist2)
        sublista1.extend(sublista2)
        sub_res.append(sublista1)
    return sub_res
```

Si le enviamos datos de prueba a esa función:

```
print(desplazar(['a', 'b', 1, 2], 0, 0))
# Desplazar el elemento 0 ('a') hasta la posición 0 por la derecha
# -> [['b', 'a', 1, 2], ['b', 1, 'a', 2], ['b', 1, 2, 'a']]

print(desplazar(['a', 'b', 1, 2], 1, -1))
# Desplazar el elemento 1 ('b') hasta la posición -1 por la derecha
# -> [['a', 1, 'b', 2]]
```

Se observa que la función devuelve todas las sublistas por las que se desplazó el elemento hasta su posición final. Con esto ya se puede pasar al subproblema 2

**Problema 2:** Enviarle a la función una lista, la posición del elemento a desplazar y su posición final.
La primera lista que se enviará es la unión de `lista1` y `lista2` y en las siguentes iteraciones del `while` la lista será el último subresultado `res[-1][:]` de la iteración anterior.
El primer elemento que se desplazará será `len(lista1) - 1` o sea, la posición del último elemento, `j`, de la `lista1` original.
La posición final del elemento `j` será `k` desde la derecha, inicialmente será `0`, el siguiente será `-1`, luego `-2` y asi sucesivamente.

Eso traducido a código queda algo como:

```
def combinar(lista1, lista2):
    k = len(lista1) - 1 # Posición del primer elemento a desplazar
    lista1.extend(lista2) # lista1 unida a lista2
    j = 0 # Posición final del primer elemento
    res = [lista1]
    while k >= 0:
        res.extend(desplazar(res[-1][:], k, j)) # (*) Ver notas
        k -= 1
        j -= 1
    return res
```

Enviándole datos a esa función, se obtiene la salida deseada:

```
print(combinar(['a'], [1, 2]))
# La salida es:
# [['a', 1, 2], [1, 'a', 2], [1, 2, 'a']]

print(combinar(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2]))
# La salida es:
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2], ['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 2], ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 'c'], 
# ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c'], ['a', 1, 2, 'b', 'c'], [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'c'], 
# [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']]
```

(*) Nota: La parte `[:]` de `res[-1][:]` es para hacer una copia de la lista, ya que python pasa las estructuras de datos (listas, diccionarios, etc) por referencia y no por valor. Esto quiere decir que si se altera ese valor en la función, también se va a alterar en la respuesta: Por ejemplo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(3)
>>> print(a, b)
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
# Observar que la lista 'a' también recibió el elemento 3.
```

Answer (score 1):

Propongo esta solución:

```
def intercalar(lista1, lista2):
    lista = lista1 + lista2
    tot1 = [x for x in range(len(lista1))]
    tot2 = [-len(lista2) + x for x in range(len(lista2))]
    total = tot1 + tot2
    for perm in itertools.permutations(total, len(lista)):
        perm1 = [x for x in perm if x >= 0]
        perm2 = [x for x in perm if x < 0]

        if perm1 == tot1 and perm2 == tot2:
            linea = [lista[i] for i in perm]
            print(linea)
```

La idea es usar `itertools.permutations` para generar todas las permutaciones posibles en base a las dos listas. En esta secuencia están incluidas permutaciones no deseadas (serán luego descartadas), que alternan el orden relativo de los elementos.

En lugar de permutar sobre los elementos, permuto sobre los índices. Los índices de la primera lista son positivos; los de la segunda lista son negativos, a fin de que el orden de los índices coincida con el orden de los elementos, y no se confunda una lista con la otra.

Con los datos del OP,

```
lista1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lista2 = [1, 2]
total = [0, 1, 2, -2, -1]
```

formamos la lista `total`, que tendrá los indices de cada elemento dentro de su lista.

Cada permutacion devuelta es examinada para separar los índices en dos listas: índices positivos y negativos. Si el orden relativo se ha mantenido, entonces `lista1` debe ser igual a `tot1` (igual `lista2`).

Uso los indices para recuperar los elementos e imprimirlos. Si el índice es positivo, uso `lista1`; si no, `lista2`.

```
import itertools

lista1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lista2 = [1, 2]

def intercalar(lista1, lista2):
    lista = lista1 + lista2
    tot1 = [x for x in range(len(lista1))]
    tot2 = [-len(lista2) + x for x in range(len(lista2))]
    total = tot1 + tot2
    for perm in itertools.permutations(total, 5):
        perm1 = [x for x in perm if x >= 0]
        perm2 = [x for x in perm if x < 0]

        if perm1 == tot1 and perm2 == tot2:
            linea = [lista[i] for i in perm]
            print(linea)

intercalar(lista1, lista2)
```

produce:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2]
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 2]
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 'c']
['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2]
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c']
['a', 1, 2, 'b', 'c']
[1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2]
[1, 'a', 'b', 2, 'c']
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'c']
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo siento, no me resistí. Al ver lo que ponías `[a]&[1, 2]` pensé que habías creado una clase y redefinido el método `__and__`, pero al leer el código me di cuenta que no es así y además hay demasiado código y no sé cual sea tu error ya que no lo mencionas.

Como no resistí ver un código que no redefina el operador `&` para intercalar las listas me vi en la *"obligación"* de crear uno y te lo comparto.

Creo que todo lo que hice es algo fácil, pero aún así trataré de explicar cada cosa ya que parece que eres principiante en python.

---

### Solución

Lo primero que hacemos es crear una clase, en mi caso la llamé `Lista`, y declaramos el inicializador para que reciba un parámetro que será una lista de python. Luego tenemos la posibilidad de redefinir los *dunder_methods* por lo que podemos crear un método llamado `__and__` que es el que invoca python al encontrar el operador `&`. Este operador mayormente representa la operación *bitwise and* pero algunos módulos, como pandas, lo redefinen para hacer que se comporte de forma diferente y esto es lo mismo que nosotros haremos, redefiniremos el método y haremos que haga una "*intercalación de listas*".

El método `__and__` recibe 2 parámetros, el primero es la clase misma, comúnmente especificada como `self` y el segundo es el otro objeto con el que se hace la operación (que por conveniencia será del mismo tipo, es decir un elemento de clase `Lista`). La operación será expresada como `a&b`.

Una vez teniendo esto claro el único trabajo es simplificar tu código para intercalar las listas. Esto lo hice teniendo en cuenta que lo que quieres es hallar las combinaciones de ambas listas, lo cual he logrado con 2 ciclos `for` (que posteriormente cambie el último a un `while` y no usé el módulo `itertools` ya que seguramente no te dejan). El primer ciclo nos sirve para iterar en la lista `a` y el segundo para iterar en la lista `b` y es en este ciclo donde ocurre la magia. En este ciclo vamos a ir moviendo (literalmente) el elemento del ciclo ciclo anterior y así hasta que este alcance el ultimo lugar en la lista.

```py
class Lista():
    def __init__(self, lista):
        self.lista = lista

    def __and__(self, other): #other representa la lista b en a&b
        result = [] #se guarda el resultado
        new = self.lista + other.lista #union de ambas listas
        result.append(new) 
        new=new.copy() #creamos una copia de la lista

        for x in self.lista:
            n = 0 #un contador para mover el elemento de posición
            while new.index(x)!=len(new)-1: #no paramos hasta que este en el ultimo lugar
                new.remove(x) #quitamos el elemento
                n+=1 #nos movemos una posición
                new.insert(n,x) #lo insertamos en la nueva posicion
                result.append(new.copy()) #guardamos una copia de la lista
        return result 

#creamos nuestas listas de tipo Lista
a = Lista(["a","b"])
b = Lista([1,2])

print(a&b) #intercalamos las listas
```

El resultado es:

```
[['a', 'b', 1, 2],
 ['b', 'a', 1, 2],
 ['b', 1, 'a', 2],
 ['b', 1, 2, 'a'],
 [1, 'b', 2, 'a'],
 [1, 2, 'b', 'a'],
 [1, 2, 'a', 'b']]
```

Seguramente no se te mostrará de esta forma (formateada), pero puedes hacerlo usando el módulo `pprint` que formatea este tipo de salidas. No te preocupes es solo un módulo para ver la salida de forma ordenada y no interfiere con el programa.

### Aclaraciones

Algo que hay que aclarar es que el programa devuelve algunas listas de más dado que en realidad se encuentran las permutaciones, no he tenido mucho tiempo y por ahora lo dejo así, pero creo que fácil de arreglar.

Otra cosa es que no es muy *seguro*, a lo que me refiero es que fallará si alguna de las listas tiene elementos repetidos por ejemplo si haces `Lista(["a","a"])&Lista([1,2])`. Esto se debe al uso de `remove()` que siempre elimina el primer elemento que coincida con el que se le pasa, lo mejor sería usar `pop(n)`.

---

En cuanto pueda haré algunas mejoras al código y editaré la respuesta. Por ahora me contento con el funcionamiento de esto y espero que te sirva. Cualquier duda que tengas me la puedes hacer en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Entiendo tu deseo de responder, pero ten cuidado, [podrían bloquear tu cuenta para dar respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) y no parece facil salir de un bloqueo así. Sobre que opino de tu respuesta, la verdad no se, pero me preocupe en cuanto vi un voto negativo.

Comment: @DanteS. eso sería para alguien quien tiene muchas respuestas votadas en negativo. Este es mi segundo voto negativo durante mi estadía en SO, el primero fue cuando recién entre. Bueno, a mi también me preocupa ya que significa que algo hice mal, pero sin un comentario poco puedo hacer para corregir el "error"

Comment: Si alguien considera que la respuesta es mala, entonces la borraré. Más que todo me entusiasmé por el operador `&` y esto queda como aprendizaje para mi, lo que quería era compartir esto con otros, pero si no les interesa ni modo. Me esforcé escribiendo la respuesta para que sea entendible por todos

Comment: Se que es para los que tienen muchas respuestas votadas en negativo. Por eso mismo te advierto, para que no empieces a dejarte llevar demasiado y evitar así que te bloqueen.

Comment: Bueno gracias. Crees que la respuesta es mala?

Comment: De nada! Que sea mala no creo, la respuesta parece bien explicada. Si incumple lo que espera la comunidad, es algo en lo que soy medio inseguro y rara vez me meto. Y este caso no es parte de esos "rara vez". Si, he emitido votos de cierre, pero en esos casos estaba casi seguro de mi desicion.

Comment: Sería mucho más claro definir una función `intercalar()` (o un juego de funciones similares). El nombre explicita su intención y el IDE te mostrará automáticamente sus parámetros. El redefinición de operadores se presta para todo tipo de malas interpretaciones y problemas.